# Ruby 1.8.7 / Rails 3 Routing: Controller#Index keeps trying to render Controller#Show

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, integration-testing

I'm sure I'm just adding on to the myriad of existing routing errors questions by posting this, but I wouldn't be posting this if I wasn't working on this problem for the past few days with no success. I'm currently going through the process of combining two rails applications, thus far some things work and some things don't. At the moment I'm trying to get Application B's routes to work within Application A. They're both running off of rails 3 and both work fine as stand-alone applications. I figured if I simply copy and pasted the routes from application B into application A everything would work nicely but this doesn't seem to be the case.

As of current, this is my Routes.rb file and I'm trying to get the index page of the forum controller to display with the following url http://localhost:3000/forums/:

```
ProTemplateApp31::Application.routes.draw do

    resources :topics do
      member do
        get 'show_new'
      end
    end

    resources :forums
    resources :posts 
    resources :blog_entries 
    resources :category 
    match "login" => 'forums/index'

    devise_for :users

    root :to => "home#index"   
end
```

Which produces this error message:

> Routing Error
>
> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"forums"}

Here is my routes file after doing a rake routes:

```
      show_new_topic GET    /topics/:id/show_new(.:format)   {:action=>"show_new", :controller=>"topics"}
              topics GET    /topics(.:format)                {:action=>"index", :controller=>"topics"}
                     POST   /topics(.:format)                {:action=>"create", :controller=>"topics"}
           new_topic GET    /topics/new(.:format)            {:action=>"new", :controller=>"topics"}
          edit_topic GET    /topics/:id/edit(.:format)       {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"topics"}
               topic GET    /topics/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"show", :controller=>"topics"}
                     PUT    /topics/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"update", :controller=>"topics"}
                     DELETE /topics/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"topics"}
              forums GET    /forums(.:format)                {:action=>"index", :controller=>"forums"}
                     POST   /forums(.:format)                {:action=>"create", :controller=>"forums"}
           new_forum GET    /forums/new(.:format)            {:action=>"new", :controller=>"forums"}
          edit_forum GET    /forums/:id/edit(.:format)       {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"forums"}
               forum GET    /forums/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"show", :controller=>"forums"}
                     PUT    /forums/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"update", :controller=>"forums"}
                     DELETE /forums/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"forums"}
               posts GET    /posts(.:format)                 {:action=>"index", :controller=>"posts"}
                     POST   /posts(.:format)                 {:action=>"create", :controller=>"posts"}
            new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)             {:action=>"new", :controller=>"posts"}
           edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)        {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts"}
                post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)             {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"}
                     PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)             {:action=>"update", :controller=>"posts"}
                     DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)             {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"posts"}
      category_index GET    /category(.:format)              {:action=>"index", :controller=>"category"}
                     POST   /category(.:format)              {:action=>"create", :controller=>"category"}
        new_category GET    /category/new(.:format)          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"category"}
       edit_category GET    /category/:id/edit(.:format)     {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"category"}
            category GET    /category/:id(.:format)          {:action=>"show", :controller=>"category"}
                     PUT    /category/:id(.:format)          {:action=>"update", :controller=>"category"}
                     DELETE /category/:id(.:format)          {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"category"}
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)         {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)         {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)        {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)        {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)    {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)   {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)        {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)          {:action=>"cancel", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
   user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                 {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}    
new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)         {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}   
edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)            {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                     PUT    /users(.:format)                 {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                     DELETE /users(.:format)                 {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                root        /                                {:controller=>"home", :action=>"index"}
```

Another thing to note is that I do in fact have all the required controllers/views and there are no spelling errors as far as I'm aware.

Any thoughts as to what might be causing these errors? I have tried restarting my server multiple times but no dice.

Comment: Quote is not to be used for large amounts of code.

Comment: Noted, I had a screenshot prepared that got it all but I'm not high enough rep to post screenshots. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a link to the show action of my forums on the index page I was trying to reach. The link wasn't using the correct href url so abstracting from what was shown in my rake routes. I simply needed to replace the url with `forum_path(forum_object)`